# React JS BrowserRouter + Express JS + Nginx with proxy not rooting correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, nginx

My problem is that I want to pass parameters to the React component via the URL. If I try that via the localhost dev environment, everything works fine.

My problem only occurs when I deploy the React app to my runtime server. (https://panel.nuerk-solutions.de/dvb)

I use https://pterodactyl.io/, which is actual a GamesServerPanel.

Now Pterodactyl only manages Docker containers for me and can open ports for these. So far, everything works fine. In addition to that, I use an Express for the server (see Config).
I then configured a proxy in my Nginx-Config that redirects the IP address to this domain: https://panel.nuerk-solutions.de/dvb. Everything still works so far. Only when I try to set my parameters in the URL: https://panel.nuerk-solutions.de/dvb/Hbf/3/5 then only a white page appers, with an error, which can be seen below. For some reason it tries to access `/dvb/Hbf/3` and then the files. Why is that so?

I only want to pass the parameters `Hbf`,`3` and `5` to the components.

Thank you for your help!

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4y4B.png)

**Docker Container - Express Log:**

```
container@pterodactyl~ Server marked as running...
v16.6.1
:/home/container$ npm install && npm run start

up to date, audited 55 packages in 843ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

> backend@1.0.0 start
> node index

Server Ready!
GET /dvb 304 5.365 ms - -
GET /static/css/main.a334b880.chunk.css 304 0.810 ms - -
GET /static/css/2.ed1298f3.chunk.css 304 0.411 ms - -
GET /static/js/main.5eb45bf9.chunk.js 304 0.424 ms - -
GET /static/js/2.6ba6ee6f.chunk.js 304 0.522 ms - -
GET /manifest.json 304 0.513 ms - -
GET /logo192.png 304 0.550 ms - -
------------------------
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/5 200 4.206 ms - 2286
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/static/css/main.a334b880.chunk.css 200 1.639 ms - 2286
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/static/js/main.5eb45bf9.chunk.js 200 2.164 ms - 2286
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/static/js/2.6ba6ee6f.chunk.js 200 2.228 ms - 2286
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/static/css/2.ed1298f3.chunk.css 200 2.379 ms - 2286
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/manifest.json 200 1.303 ms - 2286
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/favicon.ico 200 1.396 ms - 2286
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/static/css/main.a334b880.chunk.css 304 1.040 ms - -
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/static/css/2.ed1298f3.chunk.css 304 0.600 ms - -
GET /dvb/Hbf/3/manifest.json 304 0.743 ms - -
```

**Nginx Config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name panel.nuerk-solutions.de;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;    
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    
    server_name panel.nuerk-solutions.de;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/origin-pull-ca.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://134.255.234.93:2086;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

**React code:**

```
import {DvbWidget} from "./dvb/Dvb";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Quote from "./qutoe/Quote";

function App() {
    return (
        <Router
        forceRefresh={true}>
            <Navbar>
                <NavItem icon={<PlusIcon/>} destinationPath="/dvb"/>
                <NavItem icon={<BellIcon/>} destinationPath="/quote"/>
                <NavItem icon={<MessengerIcon/>}/>
                <NavItem icon={<CaretIcon/>}>
                    <DropdownMenu/>
                </NavItem>
            </Navbar>

            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/dvb/:stop?/:amount?/:offset?"
                       children={() => <DvbWidget name={"MainStaion"}/>}/>
                <Route path="/quote" children={() => <Quote />}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

**Express Code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require("morgan");

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(2086);
console.log("Server Ready!");
```

Comment: Are you using CRA? it looks like you have incorrectly specified the `PUBLIC_URL` variable.
For example, chunk url should be `"/static/js/2.6ba6ee6f.chunk.js"` instead `"./static/js/2.6ba6ee6f.chunk.js"`

Comment: @Denwakeup if you mean with CRA, Create React App then yes. I didnt modified anything in the index.html file. In the manifest.json, I updated the "start_url" from `/` to `.` . How can I correct the `PUBLIC_URL` in order to match your example?
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: As I see it works well now. Have you made any changes? 
`PUBLIC_URL` - you can specify it at build time (`PUBLIC_URL=yourHomePage npm run build`) or using "homepage" inside the package.json file.

Comment: ps Basically if app is hosted at the server root you do not need to specify homepage in package.json (just remove it) and check that the PUBLIC_URL variable is not present in the environment.

Comment: @Denwakeup I think I solved the issue. Your answer prompted me to check again, with what the `%PUBLIC_URL%` is being replaced with. I noticed that I had it in my package.json files under `homepage`: `. / `, As well as in my manifest.json under` start_url` `.` Since that didn't make sense to me, I set both to `/`. It works fine.
Thanks!

Comment: ps. yeah that pretty much how I did it.

Comment: @Denwakeup Thank you for your help. Everything works so far now. Another topic. Could you give me a catchphrase or help me? I can't find a solution for this on the Internet. How you can set parameters like this: https://example.com?stop=Test&amount=4

Comment: You're welcome!
As for the query parameters, please check the following example. 
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters
I hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the `start_url` in manifest.json and `homepage` in package.json to `/`.